# Program not in work : Segmentation fault is occur

Tags: c

FACE faculty told us that sacnf, get() , etc like function don't work in TCS campus commune portal so instead of scanf() should used atoi() ,atof(), function which is in "stdlib" library, so I tried to run simple addition program on gcc compiler so there is Segmentation fault whereas there is no error in program.
What is this Segmentation fault?

Comment: The seg fault means there is an error in the program - or the input depending on how you look at things. I can't guess the error without seeing the code

Comment: Segmentation fault occurs during run time, so compiler won't throw any errors if code syntax is proper. You need to add some code of what you tried.

Answer (score -1):

A segmentation fault (aka segfault) is a common condition that causes programs to crash. Segmentation faults are caused by a program trying to read or write an illegal memory location.